# Why can't I overwrite the linear gradient?

Tags: css

I am fairly new, and I am faced with a problem that I cannot understand. I did a lot of research to try to solve the problem, but I did not come across anything convincing.

I apply a linear gradient to the body of the document but when I try to apply another color to one of the children the linear gradient hides the color that I am trying to apply to the element.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #7cffeb, #5839bc);
}

.main-container {
  background-image: url("../images/image.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.1;
  height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  left: 25%;
  background-color: cornsilk; /* this line does not have any effect */
  background-color: cornsilk !important; /* this line either */
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

If someone could enlighten me, it would help me.

Thank you !

**UPDATE** Thanks to your answers, I was able to solve the problem. I simply changed the structure of my HTML document.

```html
<body>
<div class="main-container"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: `height: 100%` of the empty innermost element will computed to 0px unless it is absolutely or fix positioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have `opacity: 0.1` on `.main-container`. All children will inherit this opacity, and giving them `opacity: 1` effectively means 100% of 0.1 - it will not overwrite the parent style.